# Checking if Custom Control is visible in PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two placeholders/panels:

**This panel is displayed for logged-in members.**

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelLogged" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <cc:MyControl1 runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

**This panel is displayed for NON logged-in members.**

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelNotLogged" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <cc:MyControl2 runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

In Page.Page_Load event, I'm showing/hiding one of those panels. In both custom controls I have Page_Load event, where I'm populating them/making some tasks. However, Page_Load event is called on both custom controls all the time, even if Panel has property Visible="false".

How can I call only one Page_Load of the control which is currently visible? I tried with DataBind() event but with no success.

Comment: Those controls extend System.Web.UI.UserControl

Answer (score 0):

In the Page_Load of the Controls you can use FindControl on the parent and check the visibility of the panel.

```
    Panel panel = Parent.FindControl("PanelLogged") as Panel;
    if (panel.Visible == true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

You could also load the control you need in code behind, that way only one control is loaded instead of two.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    MyControl1 control = (MyControl1)LoadControl("~/MyControl1.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(control);
}
else
{
    MyControl2 control = (MyControl2)LoadControl("~/MyControl2.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(control);
 }
```

MyControl1 and MyControl2 are probably your classnames for the controls. You can find those in the code behind of your control.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class MyControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
```